# lotto gui application that generates random numbers

Tags: c++, qt4

```
#ifndef LOTTO_H
#define LOTTO_H
#include <QWidget>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QGridLayout>

class lotto : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    //widget data members
    QLabel* numbersLabel;
    QTextEdit* numEdit;
    QPushButton* lotusButton;

public slots:
     int generateLotteryNumbers ();
     void displayNumbers();

public:
    lotto();
};

#endif // LOTTO_H




     #include "lotto.h"
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <time.h>
        #include <QWidget>
        #include <QGridLayout>
        #include <iostream>
        #include <sstream>
        #include <QString>
        #include "lotto.h"
        using namespace std;

        lotto::lotto(){
            setWindowTitle("Lotto Numbers");
            QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout(this);
            lotusButton = new QPushButton ("Lotto Numbers");
            numbersLabel = new QLabel ("Your lucky numbers are:");
            numEdit = new QTextEdit();
            layout->addWidget(lotusButton, 0,0);
            layout->addWidget(numbersLabel, 1,0);
            layout->addWidget(numEdit, 1,1);
            setLayout(layout);
          //connect signals and slots
            connect(lotusButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this, SLOT(generateLotteryNumbers()));
        }
        int lotto::generateLotteryNumbers (){
            srand ( time(NULL) );
               int i, j, num, duplicates, numbers[6];
                for ( i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
                   do {
                       num = 1 + rand()%49;
                       duplicates = 0;
                       for ( j = 0; j < i; j++ ) {
                           if ( numbers[ j ] == num ) duplicates = 1;
                       }
                   }
                   while (duplicates);
                   numbers[ i ] = num;
            }

        }

        void lotto::displayNumbers(){
            numEdit->setText(QString::number(generateLotteryNumbers()));
        }
```

I try to display 6 lotto numbers in a textedit box. Is it better to use a lineedit? The textbox remains empty when I click the lotto number button. Why? How can I get the textbox (or the linebox) to display the numbers?

I tried this:

```
void lotto::displayNumbers(){
    srand ( time(NULL) );
       int i, j, num, duplicates, numbers[6];
        for ( i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
           do {
               num = 1 + rand()%49;
               duplicates = 0;
               for ( j = 0; j < i; j++ ) {
                   if ( numbers[ j ] == num ) duplicates = 1;
               }
           }
           while (duplicates);
           numbers[ i ] = num;
    }
    numEdit->setText(QString::number(num));
}
```

and each time I click the button I get a different number (one at a time)

Comment: `The textbox remains empty when I click the lotto number button. Why?` Have you tried debugging your code? What was the result?

Comment: It displays the gui, but when I click the lotto numbers button no numbers are displayed

Comment: `and each time I click the button I get a different number (one at a time)` it happens because you set the text field text to one number each time you click a button. `numEdit->setText(QString::number(num));` You should put all the numbers from the `numbers` array to the text field instead.

Comment: show the main funcion

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from your code the `lotto::displayNumbers` method is not even being called after the button click. The button click signal is connected to the `lotto::generateLotteryNumbers` method instead.

Also I can not see any return statements in the `lotto::generateLotteryNumbers` method.

By the way you could figure it out yourself if you spend a minute in a debugger.

Comment: ok I changed it to: connect(lotusButton,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(displayNumbers())); When I click the lotto numbers button I get a 0

Comment: What do you mean by `I get a 0`? Where do you get it? What conclusion can you make after it?

Comment: the text box displays a 0

Comment: Do you know what `debugging` is? If not, you should learn it if you want to be a programmer. Open a debugger window, run you program line by line, watch variables values, watch function return values watch the call-stack. Compare what you see and what you expect to see. That is how it works. Checkout updated answer btw.

Comment: Also I can not see any return statements in the `lotto::generateLotteryNumbers` method.